# How to place text on top of image in ReportViewer

Tags: image, visual-studio-2010, textbox, report, reportviewer

I feel very silly asking this, since it seems like it just should work, but I cannot make it work and cannot find anything in the documentation about this.

The problem: I'm developing an application in Visual Studio 2010 that is utilizing ReportViewer, rendering the report locally. In the report designer, I place a textbox on top of an image. This looks fine in the designer, but when rendering the report, the textbox is rendered below the image.

Now, before you suggest it, I have tried placing a textbox on top of a rectangle (or other control) with the BackgroundImage property set. This works. But: I cannot find a way to rescale the background image to fit the control. Setting a different dpi for the background image does nothing. Simply rescaling the image to a different resolution is not an option, since I eventually want to print the report.

Does anybody have a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible unless the image and text are rendered separatly.

Just think of the reporting service as a matrix such as excel and only one item can be in each space. This is also true as when the report is rendered it is realigned acordingly.